# How to make a div fit in a single page (without scrollbars) in all the bigger screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model, responsive

I have a bootstrap model inside a div. I want to show a sign up form in that model. I don't want to extend the page beyond the viewport of the browser whether the browser is opened in a 15+ inch screen or a 13+ inch screen. In short I want to show the model to all the users on any screen size so that the they don't have to scroll the page to get the full content of the sign up form.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the div a `max-width`.

Comment: How can I decide the `max-width` value?